# pass an object : multiple uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

this is the senario of my application : I have 3 viewcontrollers, `viewcontroller1`, `viewcontroller2`, `viewcontroller3`.
in `viewcontroller1`, I have simply one button, on the click of this button I add the `viewcontroller2` , as a popup , this contain a textfield. again when I edit my textfield , I add the `viewcontroller3` wich contain only a pickerview. What I have to do is to pass the selected object from the pickerview and pass it to the textfield of `viewcontroller2` when I clik the done button.

this is my code:

```
//Viewcontroller1 : add the Viewcontroller2 
- (void)withContractAction:(id)sender
{
    Viewcontroller2 *addViewController = [[Viewcontroller2 alloc] initWithNibName:@" Viewcontroller2 " bundle:nil];

    addViewController.delegate = self;

    addViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    addViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

    [self presentModalViewController:addViewController animated:YES];

    addViewController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(150, 300, 460, 300);

    [addViewController release];
}
```

in `viewcontroller2` I add `viewcontroller3`:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{


        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        Viewcontroller3 *addViewController = [[Viewcontroller3 alloc] initWithNibName:@" Viewcontroller1" bundle:nil];
        addViewController.delegate = self;

        addViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        addViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

        [self presentModalViewController:addViewController animated:YES];

        addViewController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(50, 740, 695, 245);
               self.textfield.text = contrat.NUM_CONTRACT;
    }
}
```

viewcontroller3:

```
-(IBAction)done:(id)sender{
    Viewcontroller2 *popup = [[Viewcontroller2 alloc]init];
//contrat is my object that I need to pass , from  Viewcontroller3 to Viewcontroller2 ,so I included it into my interface in Viewcontroller2 , 
        popup.contrat = sometxt;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:popup animated:YES];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [orderForm dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [popup release];   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this: `Viewcontroller2 *popup = [[Viewcontroller2 alloc]init];`

Instead, use `ViewController3`'s `delegate` which should be the existing instance of `Viewcontroller2` rather than a new one you're inventing on the fly.

Comment: how to do that please ,I a new in objective C developement

Comment: In `textFieldDidBeginEditing` you have the line `addViewController.delegate = self;`.  So, in `done:`, you should be able to write `self.delegate.contrat = sometxt;`.  It might be a little different, depending on how `ViewController3` defines its `delegate` property.  (Show that declaration if the line I gave you causes any errors.)

Comment: but in this case , how the object could be passed from view3 that contains uipicker to view2 that contain the textfield if we don't use the pusgviewcontroller

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the first line inside `done:`.  When your program stops in the debugger, print the value of `self.delegate`.  If things are working as they should, you'll see that it's the instance of `Viewcontroller2` that created your `Viewcontroller3`...and that's what needs to be given the new object.  (If you're asking how to get `sometxt` from the picker, I don't know...I'd have to look in the documentation.)

Comment: not asking how to get the value , but how It could be passed from the view that contain the picker to the view that contain the textfield